# Can VS.Net Unit Test be run outside the IDE?

Tags: unit-testing, command-line, mstest

Is there a way you can run your UnitTest project against a compiled DLL outside of the IDE?  Basically we have testing procedures to validate code before moving into production.
I would not want to run the tests inside the IDE.  I would want to have the compiled code ready to move to production and be able to run a final test against the .dll before the final copy.

Is there some kind of Command-Line utility that could do this?  Just supply both .dlls and get a "all good" report of some kind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for [MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486(VS.80).aspx)

To run all tests in a specific container, you could do something like the following at a command line:

> MSTest /testcontainer:MyTestProject\bin\debug\MyTestProject.dll

- [MSTest Command Line Options for .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(VS.80).aspx)
- [MSTest Command Line Options for .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx)
- [Other Stack  Overflow related MSTest Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mstest)